# Twilio HTTP response: Not parsing XML/JSON

Tags: json, http, twilio

Using Twilio Studio, my HTTP widget obtains the following JSON from (external) endpoint:

```
{
  "response": {
     "say": "1 address found",
     "data": [
        "10707 Ewing Drive Kansas City Kansas"
     ]
   }
}
```

However, I am able to access `{{widgets.http_address_schedule.body}}` but not `{{widgets.http_address_schedule.parsed.say}}`. Twilio documentation indicates this is possible if my response is JSON.

From documentation at: https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide#rest-api

> Json: If your function returns valid Json, you should be able to
>   access it via widgets.MY_WIDGET_NAME.parsed
>
> For example, if you return {"message": "Hi", "person": {"name": "Bob",
>   "age": 40}}, you can reference that in subsequent widgets as:
>
> widgets.MY_WIDGET_NAME.parsed.message
>
> widgets.MY_WIDGET_NAME.parsed.person.name
>
> widgets.MY_WIDGET_NAME.parsed.person.age

What is the expected way to send data to be parsed by Twilio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing Twilio Studio logs, I was able to identify PHP error output embedded in the JSON response. Once the error was resolved Twilio was able to successfully parse response and provide data in `parsed` key in `{{widgets.http_address_schedule.parsed.response.say}}`